# Magento 1 rendering process : How to improve?

Tags: php, performance, magento, rendering, magento-1.9

If I analyze with "aoe profiler" the sites of my magento instance, I can see that rendering the .phtml files take the most time.

In example on low budget vps, "add to cart" can take near to 5 seconds, just for the rendering of the cart template.

On a professional vps with raid0 & SSD, it still takes 2,5 seconds.

I can't see details of rendering process, just which .phtml file and how long it took to render/load.

Is there any way to improve the rendering process of magento 1?

Comment: The best ways we've found to improve Magento performance is to use flat tables, give it a tonne of iron (minimum of AWS m4.xlarge) and slap a Full Page Cache on it. The FPC won't help performance through the basket -> checkout though (those pages shouldn't be cached).

Comment: However, this question should probably be migrated to https://magento.stackexchange.com/ - it's too broad for SO.